# Getting runtime Eval() label to compare to Session["userName"]

Tags: c#, session, listview, button, label

I need to get a label during runtime so that i can compare to the Session["userName"] and choose to show buttons after the comparison.
I have look around and this seems to be the solution but i've run onto trouble as i only get null during runtime.

```
UserName:
            <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserName") %>' />
            <br />
```

So, this is the label inside a "ListView1" i need what Eval finds during each iteration of pumping out of the attached database.

```
    <% Label lbl = (Label) ListView1.FindControl("userName");
       string userName = lbl.Text;
        if (Session["userName"].ToString() == userName)
        {%>
    <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
    <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
    <% }%>
```

and this is my attempt at retrieving the label.Text. i know it is something similar to this but i might be doing it wrong... well i am doing it wrong.

Thanks you very much for any information you can provide as i have just spent about 10 hours changing the ways i could achieve this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
Visible='<%# Session["userName"].ToString() == Eval("UserName").ToString() %>'
```

on each of the `Button` controls.

Comment: i gets around so much hassle and is very neat